Create swipe category on user profile
I want to add to my user profile the swipe category like instagram has : https://imgur.com/a/ALeXB73 but I don't know what package I should use or if there is a package that has this

you can use DefaultTabBar widget

Good News! There is no need to use a package as there is already a widget from the flutter library that handles this pretty good. The widget is DefaultTabController. It allows you to specify tabs and its contents. An Example could be:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabsExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabsExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: const TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'LEFT'), //the button shown at the top
              Tab(text: 'RIGHT'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: const TabBarView(
          children: [
            // First widget is the page that opens when the left tab button is clicked
            Center(
              // Any widget you want to display
              child: Text('LEFT'),
            ),
            // Second widget is the page that opens when the right tab button is clicked
            Center(
              // Any widget you want to display

              child: Text('RIGHT'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

OR
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabsExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabsExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: const Column(
          children: [
            TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'LEFT'), //the button shown at the top
                Tab(text: 'RIGHT'),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  // First widget is the page that opens when the left tab button is clicked
                  Center(
                    // Any widget you want to display
                    child: Text('LEFT'),
                  ),
                  // Second widget is the page that opens when the right tab button is clicked
                  Center(
                    // Any widget you want to display
                    child: Text('RIGHT'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

In your case you would replace Tab(text: 'LEFT') with something like Tab(icon: yourIcon) or you could also specify a custom widget to have as the button - Tab(widget: Text('LEFT'))
The content of the page is specified in the children parameter. (first tab has first child as its page)

But if I don't want it in the appbar

You can use it outside of the appbar as well.
You just have to put the TabBar widget anywhere you like. You could put it in body or any other place. The only condition is that it has to be a child of DefaultTabController (under the DefaultTabController in the widget tree)

Try below code hope its help to you.
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text('Hello, World!'),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /
                1.5, // change it on your need
            child: DefaultTabController(
              length: 2,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.green[50],
                    child: Center(child: Text("TITLE")),
                  ),
                  TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Icon(Icons.menu),
                      Icon(Icons.person),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TabBarView(
                      children: [
                        ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: 5,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                              Text("item builder $index"),
                        ),
                        ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: 10,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                              Text("$index item builder"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 150,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: const Center(
              child: Text(
                'Your Widget if you want',
              ),
            ),
          ),Container(
            height: 150,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: const Center(
              child: Text(
                'Your Widget if you want',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),

